# How to extract the file?

Tags: command-line, scripts, 20.04, extract

The following shell statement downloads a file:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/latest |\
        grep browser_download |\
        grep $opsys |\
        cut -d '"' -f 4 |\
        xargs curl -O -L |\
```

and I have tried to add additional statement to extract the file:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/latest |\
        grep browser_download |\
        grep $opsys |\
        cut -d '"' -f 4 |\
        xargs curl -O -L |\
        tar xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   648  100   648    0     0   1674      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1670
100 10.9M  100 10.9M    0     0  3863k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 6833k

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

But as you can see, I've got an error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Perl-type regular expression to simplify the grep, and xargs needs `-d '\n' because the URLs are one per line:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/latest |grep -Po 'browser_download_url"[^"]+"\K[^"]+' |xargs -d '\n' curl -L -O
```

and then in a *separate step* uncompress all the *.tar.gz* files:

```
tar xf *.tar.gz
```

If you need one statement, you can connect them together with `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

The `-O` option means

> ```
>    -O, --remote-name
>           Write output to a local file named like the remote file we  get.
>           (Only  the file part of the remote file is used, the path is cut
>           off.)
>
>           The file will be saved in the current working directory.
> ```

so there's nothing going into your pipe to `tar`. To have `curl` write to standard output instead, remove the `-O` option.